# Angular2 date range picker format date string

Tags: angular, datepicker, calendar, bootstrap-datepicker, daterangepicker

I am using this calendar on my Angular2/Spring web application:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-daterangepicker

http : // www. daterangepicker . com/

**I am facing the problem of formatting the date output.** From the official documentation this is the object that is responsible for formatting the date:

> locale.format: "MM/DD/YY" // which returns 05/13/2017

However, I am interested in more user-friendly output. Something like: **May 2017**.

How am I suppose to do this? Where can I found letters that can format my date in Javascript (like this in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Thank you very much for the replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you I'd save myself the hassle of working with Dates in Javascript and download [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/). If you're using npm you can install it with

```
npm install moment --save
```

Dates are a pain to work with in vanilla JS so moment is a really powerful library that lets you "parse, validate, manipulate, and display dates and times" super easily. To use it in your Angular2 Component you just need to import it in your component after downloading it.

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

Then you can format your output date using the `format()` function.

```
let rangePickerValue = new Date(); // example date
moment(rangePickerValue).format('MMMM YYYY'); // May 2017
```

You can see what sort of time and date output options there are in moment's documentation: [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/). For examlpe, `MMMM` outputs the full month's name (January, February, March...) while `MMM` prints (Jan, Feb, Mar...).

Comment: Actually, I managed to deal with the problem without Momentjs. However, it helped me to realize which letters I can use to format my date. The answer to my solution is format('MMM DD'). Thank you my brother. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the DatePipe

```
expression | date: format
```

example

```
{{ date | date: "MMMM yyyy" /* your format */ }}
```

result: May 2017

Comment: I can't use any pipe because I don't have the date that needs to be transformed at that moment. Therefore, in the official documentation we need to use locale object to set the format that will apply once the user select the date.